# SQL Server 2005 running at 97% CPU usage

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance

How can I findout which statements are using the CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this script.  You will need to modify as you see fit to filter apps, last batch time, etc...

```
SELECT 
top 50
 D.text SQLStatement,
 A.program_name,
 A.Session_ID SPID,
 ISNULL(B.status,A.status) Status,
 A.login_name Login,
 A.host_name HostName,
 C.BlkBy, 
 DB_NAME(B.Database_ID) DBName,
 B.command,
 ISNULL(B.cpu_time, A.cpu_time) CPUTime,
 ISNULL((B.reads + B.writes),(A.reads + A.writes)) DiskIO, 
 A.last_request_start_time LastBatch
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_sessions A 
   LEFT JOIN
    sys.dm_exec_requests B
    ON A.session_id = B.session_id
   LEFT JOIN
       (
        SELECT 
                A.request_session_id SPID,
                B.blocking_session_id BlkBy
           FROM sys.dm_tran_locks as A
             INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks as B
            ON A.lock_owner_address = B.resource_address
        ) C
    ON A.Session_ID = C.SPID
   OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) D
where  D.text is not null
order by cputime desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Management Studio > Current Activity

or

Execute sp_who2 in a query window

If it's an ongoing issue you could also run a trace to get more detailed info over time.